# Function will not update variable

Tags: javascript, html, global-variables

The variable `status` is set to "uncheck" and needs to be updated to "done" using the `change()` function.

Ultimately what needs to happen When button with id `randomIdTwo` is pressed, The completeTodo() function is called which causes the list item to be removed from its current div "list", appended to the div "complete-list", and the change() function updates the value of the "status" variable from "uncheck" to "done".

Everything works except the `change()` function.

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function addTodo() {
  var value = document.getElementById('input').value;
  var status = "uncheck";
  var randomId = Math.random();
  var randomIdTwo = Math.random();

  function change() {
    status = "done";
  };

  const item = `<li>
                    <div class="item">
                       <div class="complete">
                        <button id="` + randomIdTwo + `" class="${status}"></button>
                       </div>
    
                       <p class="text">${value}</p>
    
                        <div class="remove">
                           <button id="` + randomId + `" class="todo"></button>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </li>`;
  const position = "beforeend";

  list.insertAdjacentHTML(position, item);
  document.getElementById(randomId).addEventListener('click', function removeTodo() {
    var item = this.closest('li');
    item.remove();
  });
  document.getElementById(randomIdTwo).addEventListener('click', function completeTodo() {
    var item = this.closest('li');
    item.remove();
    document.getElementById("completelist").appendChild(item);
    change();
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources/CSS/reset.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources/CSS/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <div id="datetime"></div>
      <div id="ampm"></div>
      <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Add an item" />
      <button id="button" type="button"><img src="./img/additem4.png"></button>
    </header>
    <div id="list">
    </div>

    <div id="divline"></div>

    <div id="completelist">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="resources/JS/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You never use the variable after you change it. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Do you think that assigning `status` will change the class of the button?

Comment: @Barmar The reason Im trying to do that is because as it is, currently set to uncheck, its being effected by a certain CSS rule via the string interpolation. I want it to be effected by another css rule called "done". When I manually change the value of status to "done", the desired CSS rule goes into effect. Im just trying to accomplish that change using a function. Is that possible?

Comment: When you do `const item = \`...${status}...\`;` you are generating a string from the template and the current value of `status`. You are then using that string to build a `<li>` element. Even if the string magically also changed just because you changed `status` (it won't), that still wouldn't also magically change the item that was created based on that string. This is why todo lists require you to store the `status` of *each item*, using an array.

Comment: @ChrisG Im sorry perhaps Im misunderstanding you, but on my end the value of status is currently working as I wanted it to. If I change `var status = "uncheck"; ` to `var status = "done"; ` manually, the desired change occurs.  Are you saying that this is not possible to change with a function and is only possible manually as I have been doing?

Comment: You can absolutely change the variable, but you have to re-run the other commands, too. Changing the `status` variable *after* the `<li>` has been added will not affect it in any way. Again, you're setting `item` to a bunch of HTML *once*. You would have to do that **again** after changing `status` for the change to end up in `item`.

Comment: Here's example code demonstrating this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/h07st2ow/

Comment: @ChrisG Could you post an example of what you mean? like what edit should I make? Im just really trying to finish this even though I might not have taken the best approach.  Im teaching myself and its taken a while to get this far with this project. This is like the second to last thing I need to do.

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks you I will check this out.

Comment: @ChrisG I understand what your saying in your example but Im not sure how to apply the concept to the code I have. Do you think you could post en exemple of how i would have to edit my code in order for it to work?

Comment: If you're going to move the `<li>` to a different container element, you can just use a selector like `#completelist li` in your CSS to style it, there's no need to change that inner class in the first place. (`<li>`s are supposed to be children of `<ol>` or `<ul>`, btw)

Comment: @ChrisG the thing is I just want to target the one button on the list item. If i did something like `#completelist li .uncheck` would that work? or would I need to add every element between `#completelist` and `.uncheck` like `#completelist li .item .complete .uncheck{...}`?

Comment: No, as long as the selector is unique enough. `#completelist .uncheck` will work fine. But you can also target the button without its class: `#completelist .complete button`

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `status` variable doesn't change the class of the element. You need to update the button's `classList`

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function addTodo() {
  var value = document.getElementById('input').value;
  var status = "uncheck";
  var randomId = Math.random();
  var randomIdTwo = Math.random();

  function change(button) {
    button.classList.add("done");
    button.classList.remove("uncheck");
  };

  const item = `<li>
                    <div class="item">
                       <div class="complete">
                        <button id="` + randomIdTwo + `" class="${status}"></button>
                       </div>
    
                       <p class="text">${value}</p>
    
                        <div class="remove">
                           <button id="` + randomId + `" class="todo"></button>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </li>`;
  const position = "beforeend";

  list.insertAdjacentHTML(position, item);
  document.getElementById(randomId).addEventListener('click', function removeTodo() {
    var item = this.closest('li');
    item.remove();
  });
  document.getElementById(randomIdTwo).addEventListener('click', function completeTodo() {
    var item = this.closest('li');
    item.remove();
    document.getElementById("completelist").appendChild(item);
    change(this);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources/CSS/reset.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources/CSS/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <div id="datetime"></div>
      <div id="ampm"></div>
      <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Add an item" />
      <button id="button" type="button"><img src="./img/additem4.png"></button>
    </header>
    <div id="list">
    </div>

    <div id="divline"></div>

    <div id="completelist">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="resources/JS/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using string interpolation to set the class initially, but string interpolation does not create a data-binding between the resultant element and the variable.  So change() is being called, and status is being updated, but the value of the element you created via a string isn't seeing that change, so it's not being updated.

You would need to access the element in the DOM and change it's classList manually.